# C++ in eclipse IDE

Tags: c++, eclipse

```
struct student_info{
string name;
double midterm, final;
vector<double> homework;
};typedef struct student_info studentInfo;


vector<studentInfo> students;
studentInfo record;
string::size_type maxlen = 0;

while(read(cin, record)){
    maxlen = max(maxlen, record.name.size());

    cout << record.name << " " << record.midterm << " " << record.final << endl;

    students.push_back(record);
    cin.clear();
}

istream& read(istream& cin, studentInfo& student){

    cout << "Please Enter Student name, midterm mark and final mark: " << flush;
    cin >> student.name >> student.midterm >> student.final;

    read_hw(cin, student.homework);
    return cin;
}

istream& read_hw(istream& cin, vector<double>& homework){

    if(cin){
        homework.clear();
        cout << "Please Enter Student homework marks: " << flush;
        double grade;

        while(cin >> grade){
            homework.push_back(grade);
        }

        cin.clear();
    }
    return cin;

}
```

When the read function is called a second time it only accepts the first 2 words and skips the 3rd? Can someone maybe spot something? This is exactly from the book. Is this maybe the eclipse compiler?

I am really a beginner at C++ and self learning it from C++ Accelerated. Sorry if this seems trivial.

Comment: There's no way this is your whole code. Is your while loop really not inside a function?

Comment: Why are you doing `typedef struct student_info studentInfo;`?  If you want `student_info` to be called `studentInfo` just name it that way.  You do not have to use `typedef ` on `struct` names in C++ to use them without the `struct` keyword.

Comment: Eclipse is not a compiler, nor does it contain a compiler. It's an IDE that can use whatever compiler you set up your project to use.

Comment: I've tried completing your code to the point that I could run it, but I don't see a problem that matches your description. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

`cin >> student.name >> student.midterm >> student.final;` is unchecked IO.

`student.name` is probably safe since it's a string and can eat damn near anything, but if `student.midterm` or `student.final` is not entered correctly, `cin` will be in the error state and **will not be readable until cleared**.

Since the error is not being checked, the user will have no clue that this has happened and the result will look exactly like what OP has reported.

Solution:

All use of `cin` or any other stream, should be protected with something like:

```
if (not cin >> student.name >> student.midterm >> student.final)
{
    // clear the error
    cin.clear();
    // discard remainder of user's input
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 

    // handle error
}
```

or

```
while (not cin >> student.name >> student.midterm >> student.final)
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout << "Thou art a FOOL! Input the data correctly or face the WRATH of CROM!" << endl;
}
```

To keep badgering the user until they get it right.

`#include <limits>` to get `numeric_limits`.